# Flutter Text Field: How to add Icon inside the border

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: The Search Bar to Replicate]

I would like to add the icon in the search bar. Here is my code so far:

```
new TextField(
     decoration: new InputDecoration(
     icon: new Icon(Icons.search)
     labelText: "Describe Your Issue...",
     enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
     borderSide: const BorderSide(
       color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
   ),
  ),
```

This is the result of the code above (this is not what i want):

[image: Output of my code (this is not what i want)]

Comment: do you want a floating kind of app bar like google apps has?

Comment: ibhavikmakwana yes

Answer (score 191, accepted):

**Edited Answer**

Updating answer as my original answer doesn't actually cover the original context of the question.

You can use the `prefixIcon` in the `TextField` or in the `TextFormField` to get some widget as a leading in your `TextField`.

Example

```dart
    TextField(
//    ...,other fields
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: prefixIcon??Icon(Icons.done),
      ),
    ),
```

> PS: Do not get confuse between `prefixIcon` and `prefix` as this two
>   are different things.
>   https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/prefix.html

Also if you want to achieve something like floating app bar then you can refer to my original answer.

**Original answer**

You can use my Flutter package to implement [Floating AppBar](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rounded_floating_app_bar) in your application.

You need to add below package in your pub.

`rounded_floating_app_bar: ^0.1.0`

run `$ flutter packages get` from the command line.

Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:rounded_floating_app_bar/rounded_floating_app_bar.dart';
...
NestedScrollView(
  headerSliverBuilder: (context, isInnerBoxScroll) {
    return [
      RoundedFloatingAppBar(
        floating: true,
        snap: true,
        title: TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  },
  body: Container(),
),
```

Output:

[image: Image Output]

Comment: the below answers to use the prefixIcon is a better answer compared to what you have accepted as a solution. I would request you to mark appropriate answer as the accepted answer

Comment: He folks sorry for this, I have updated the answer with the original context of the question. PS: you can always upvote other answers.

Answer (score 35):

Use the prefixIcon in Just adjust in Boarder Radius

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFieldShow extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("Tab demo"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
            ),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.people),
                hintText: "Enter Your Name",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 32.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 32.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Try this way (using **prefixIcon**), just adjust the border radius

```
TextField(
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
            hintText: "Describe your issue",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[300], width: 32.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
              ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red[300], width: 32.0),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)))
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 12):

```
TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.pink),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
        hintText: ' Search',
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 9):

use prefixicon

```
return TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: hint,
    labelText: label,
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the InputDecoration argument prefixIcon, or suffixIcon.

**prefixIcon** will show *before* the text inside your TextField.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.done),
  ),
);
```

[prefixIcon showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BifVn.png)

**OR**

**suffixIcon** will show *after* the text inside your TextField.

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.done),
  ),
);
```

[suffixIcon showcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzCd.png)

ATTN: Code above does not include the border styling that is shown on the screenshots :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
      width: 1.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.search,
          color: Colors.grey,
          size: 20,
        ),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: "Search by Name",
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            contentPadding:
                EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
            isDense: true,
          ),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14.0,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

It will be displayed as:
[image: Flutter Text Field: How to add Icon inside the border]

Answer (score 4):

If you need to ad an icon in the Textfield use the arguments **prefixIcon** and **suffixIcon** inside it, like

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
  ),
);
```

Comment: To put an icon on the right, "suffixIcon" works for me! Thanks!