# How to create This Ui in - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Hello there I'm new to flutter and I want to achieve this certain UI. from the UI I can see -

1. At the top it has a custom search bar I don't know if it's an appbar or not.
2. It has a SizedBox or something similar below the searchbar.
3. It has A listview.builder (I already Know how to achieve this)

So I would like to ask how to achieve the first two contents of the app

here is a screenshot of the app [image]

Comment: If it's static UI, all you need is Container, TextWidgets and Row / Column. You can place SearchBar in Scaffold's Appbar by using title property of Appbar (it doesn't has to be Text), If you want more customizations, don't use Scaffold's Appbar, instead make your own and place it in Scaffold's body itself

Comment: @SankethB.K I see thanks for the info I just want to know how do I achieve that custom search bar any packages can I get or I need to customize myself

Comment: you can set prefix and suffix icons on the TextField widgets, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929495/flutter-text-field-how-to-add-icon-inside-the-border

Answer (score 0):

You can take this as an example. a similar design.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              buildTitleText(context),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              buildSearchBar(context),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              buildSecondTitle(context),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              buildContent(context)
            ],
          ),
        ),

    );
  }

  SizedBox buildSecondTitle(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 65,
      child: Row(
        children: const [
          Text(
            'Favorite Places',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text(
                'See All',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 18),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildTitleText(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,
      child: const Text(
        "What you would like to find?",
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          fontSize: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  SingleChildScrollView buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
          buildCityCard(context,
              photoName: 'img_istanbul.jpg',
              cityName: 'İstanbul',
              cityActivity: '98 Aktivite',
              cityScore: '4.8'),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
          buildCityCard(context,
              photoName: 'img_mugla.jpg',
              cityName: 'Muğla',
              cityActivity: '102 Aktivite',
              cityScore: '4.7'),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
          buildCityCard(context,
              photoName: 'img_antalya.jpg',
              cityName: 'Antalya',
              cityActivity: '98 Aktivite',
              cityScore: '4.5'),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 25,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildSearchBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 65,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: const Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(360),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                width: 2,
              )),
          labelText: "Locaiton",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildCityCard(BuildContext context,
      {required String photoName,
      required String cityName,
      required String cityActivity,
      required String cityScore}) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.7,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                color: Colors.blue,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/${photoName}"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.blue),
                Text(
                  "${cityName}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 20,
                ),
                const Icon(
                  Icons.star,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                ),
                Text(
                  "${cityScore}",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(95, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the home. If you want to use tabbar.

```
import 'package:circle_bottom_navigation_bar/circle_bottom_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:circle_bottom_navigation_bar/widgets/tab_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:inovatif/third_screen.dart';

import 'first_screen.dart';
import 'second_screen.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String routeName = 'home';

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  int currentPage = 0;

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    FirstScreen(),
    SecondScreen(),
    ThirdScreen(),
  ];

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final viewPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding;
    double barHeight;
    double barHeightWithNotch = 67;
    double arcHeightWithNotch = 67;

    if (size.height > 700) {
      barHeight = 70;
    } else {
      barHeight = size.height * 0.1;
    }

    if (viewPadding.bottom > 0) {
      barHeightWithNotch = (size.height * 0.07) + viewPadding.bottom;
      arcHeightWithNotch = (size.height * 0.075) + viewPadding.bottom;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0),
      body: _pages[currentPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: buildCircleBottomNavigationBar(
          viewPadding, barHeightWithNotch, barHeight, arcHeightWithNotch),
    );
  }

  CircleBottomNavigationBar buildCircleBottomNavigationBar(
      EdgeInsets viewPadding,
      double barHeightWithNotch,
      double barHeight,
      double arcHeightWithNotch) {
    return CircleBottomNavigationBar(
      initialSelection: currentPage,
      barHeight: viewPadding.bottom > 0 ? barHeightWithNotch : barHeight,
      arcHeight: viewPadding.bottom > 0 ? arcHeightWithNotch : barHeight,
      itemTextOff: viewPadding.bottom > 0 ? 0 : 1,
      itemTextOn: viewPadding.bottom > 0 ? 0 : 1,
      circleOutline: 15.0,
      shadowAllowance: 0.0,
      circleSize: 50.0,
      blurShadowRadius: 50.0,
      circleColor: Colors.purple,
      activeIconColor: Colors.white,
      inactiveIconColor: Colors.grey,
      tabs: getTabsData(),
      onTabChangedListener: (index) => setState(() => currentPage = index),
    );
  }

  List<TabData> getTabsData() {
    return [
      TabData(
        icon: Icons.home,
        iconSize: 25.0,
        title: 'Home',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      TabData(
        icon: Icons.phone,
        iconSize: 25,
        title: 'Emergency',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      TabData(
        icon: Icons.search,
        iconSize: 25,
        title: 'Search Place',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      // TabData(
      //   icon: Icons.alarm,
      //   iconSize: 25,
      //   title: 'Alarm',
      //   fontSize: 12,
      //   fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      // ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha Thanks I will try it out rn

Answer (score 0):

To create an page like this you will need to know about Text,SingleChildScrollView set scroll direction to horizontal,Bottom Navigation bar,Banner etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `CustomScrollView` and use `Slivers` for its children.

with this method you can create advance complex scrollable ui with powefull animations.
read about slivers.

good luck